# Offset a mask within a larger array

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I've got two numpy arrays: data, and a mask. The mask and the data are not the same size, so I imagine them like a canvas and a stamp. How can I stamp my canvas at different locations?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a canvas
canvas = np.zeros( 2500 ).reshape( 50, 50 )

# Make a "stamp" 
r = 10
xx, yy = np.mgrid[ :r * 2, :r * 2 ]
stamp = ((xx - r) ** 2 + (yy - r) ** 2) < r**2

# Draw on the canvas
canvas[stamp] = 10

# Display the drawing
plt.imshow(canvas)
plt.show()
```

I get this:
[image: what I can do]

How can I stamp at a different location to get something like this?
[image: what I'd like to do]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First crop out the rectangle (with the same size as stamp) from the canvas.

```
# Draw on the canvas
canvas[x_offset : x_offset + stamp.shape[0],
       y_offset : y_offset + stamp.shape[1]][stamp] = 10
```